# EXTJS 4 build , singleton not called?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

i am trying to make put my app in production mode ,  i face problem that my js code keep complain about missing javascript object and not run ,

in my app.js i have this

```
requires: [
    "FleetM.utility.SharedData"
],
```

and this shared data is used in all controllers and view as singleton with name SharedData , but after build , the minified js keep say that SharedData is missing  , but if i put it in console it print all values, even if i use uncompressed js  the same result , here is my SharedData class

```
Ext.define('FleetM.utility.SharedData', {
    alternateClassName: 'SharedData',
    singleton: true,
    'PreventALLUpdateDelete': 0,
    'vehicles_creation': 0,
 //..... alot of varibles here 
    'appSettings': 0,
    'user': 0,
    'i18n': 0,
    success_load: false,
    'comWizard': 0,
    constructor: function () {

        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: "USERS/GetAccessLevelData",
            method: 'GET',
            scope: this,
            success: function (response, opts) {
                var data = Ext.decode(response.responseText, true);
                try {
                    SharedData.user = data;
                    SharedData.user.Connected=1;
                } catch (err) {
                }

                try {
                    SharedData.PreventALLUpdateDelete = data.PreventALLUpdateDelete;
                    SharedData.vehicles_creation = data.vehicles_creation;

                    var language = SharedData.user.language;
                } catch (err) {
                }


                switch (language) {
                    case '0':
                        language = "En";
                        break;
                    case '1':
                        language = "Ar";
                        break;
                    default:
                        language = "En";
                        break;
                }

                this.LoadI18n(language);
                success_load: true;
            },
            failure: function (err) {
                //Ext.MessageBox.alert(SharedData.i18n.Reports.ErrorMsg, SharedData.i18n.Reports.tryAgain);
            }
        });

    },
    LoadI18n: function (language) {
        var me = this;

        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: "data/i18n" + language + ".json",
            method: 'GET',
            scope: this,
            success: function (response, opts) {
                var data = Ext.decode(response.responseText, true);
                try {
                    SharedData.i18n = data;
                } catch (err) {
                }
                me.success_load = true;
            },
            failure: function (err) {
                //Ext.MessageBox.alert(SharedData.i18n.Reports.ErrorMsg, SharedData.i18n.Reports.tryAgain);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**----UPDATE----**

> I have done add requires  for all controllers , and views , it still
>   complain

look at the images bellow ,

[image: requires exist]
[image: when i call from console i can read it]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add it to the `requires` array of each class, to have it available for all of it.
It is not enough to have it just in your `app.js`.

In development mode the missing class can be loaded dynamically, but in the production `app.js` all requires are appended in the order they need to be.

For Example: `requires["C1", "FleetM.utility.SharedData", "C2"]`

Would result in an `app.js` like

1. All the code with the requires for C1
2. All the code and requires for SharedData
3. All the code and requires for C2

When C1 needs SharedData for it's functionality it has to require it as well or SharedData is not available at that time for C1.

### Update

You can not access the singleton `FleetM.utility.SharedData` during the configuration of the class, because it is not initialized during that point.

You should be able to access it in the `constructor` method of the store.

```
constructor: function() {
    this.data = [
        id: 0,
        name: SharedData.i18n.configuration.Type_Vehicles
    ];
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

Comment: tried this put without luck , compiler keep complain , 
[WRN] Failed to resolve package FleetM.utility.SharedData
[WRN] Folder should have exactly one .pkg file: C:\Users\Administrator\bin\Sencha\Cmd\repo\pkgs\.meta\profiles
[WRN] Failed to resolve package FleetM.utility.SharedData

Comment: i have update my question with images , can you look at them please ?